# Removing audio noise (hissing) in C++ from 16bit PCM

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg

I have been going through the posts of stack overflow but I am not understanding how to remove hissing sound from my audio being grabbed from the microphone.

I implemented a simple low pass filter but I must be doing something wrong.

```
unsigned short *buf = "audio data in PCM format";
double out_sample = 0;
int sample_size = "number of samples of audio";
for (int n = 0; n < sample_size/2; n++)
{
    out_sample = (out_sample * 90 + buf[n] * 10) / 100;
    buf[n] = (unsigned short) out_sample;
}
```

The above produces really corrupt audio.

I know I need to make a low pass filter on the PCM data.  Can anyone shed some light into what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `sample_size/2` ? I am also not familiar with LPF that you provided as `out_sample` depends on all of yours previous samples. You also should be aware of that you "move" inside time domain and not frequency domain.

Comment: What you have is an IIR (infinite impulse response) filter with a slow exponential decay. It's a pretty heavy LPF. Also, the structure of the data needs to be clearer. sample_size/2 suggests you are dealing with stereo data which is probably interleaved which is typical of PCM, but your code does not show that. This would mess things up pretty badly.

Comment: Also, there are free apps that will show you the spectrum of the noise from your microphone. You should taylor your LPF based on that. Additionally, a dynamic gain can be applied during relatively quiet periods to minimize noise. None of this is very hard but you probably should get some tools to generate the needed filters. Octave or Matlab are good at this.

Answer (score 2):

PCM data is virtually always *signed* data. You're likely seeing the effect of every negative value suddenly being treated as a huge value (>32768). This is then filtered through your "low pass filter" as double values. Assuming that you had zero DC offset to start with, your filter will produce a DC average near 32768, but with a rather unpredictable and not acoustically sensible signal on top.